# How does code that repeats letters work?

Tags: c, function

I have recently started learning C and I have the following piece of code that I have a hard time understanding.

Basically it's a function that takes a string and displays it,
repeating each alphabetical character as many times as its alphabetical index, followed by a newline.

```
#include <unistd.h>

int ft_is_alpha(char c)
{
  if ((c >= 'a') && (c <= 'z'))
    return (0);
  else
    return (1);

}

int ft_count(char c)
{
  int k;
  k = (c - 'a');
  return (k);
}

void ft_print(char **argv)
{
  int i;
  int j;
  i = 0;
  j = 0;
  while (argv[1][i])
  {
    if (ft_is_alpha(argv[1][i]))
    {
      write(1, &argv[1][i], 1);
    }
    else
    {
      while (j <= ft_count(argv[1][i]))
      {
        write(1, &argv[1][i], 1);
        j++;
      }
      j = 0;
    }
    i++;
  }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  if (argc != 2)
  {
    write(1, "\n", 1);
    return (0);
  }
  ft_print(argv);
  write(1, "\n", 1);
  return (0);
}
```

result:

```
 ./a.out "abcd"
    abbcccdddd
```

What I don't understand is how `ft_print` is working and where the code multiplies the letters. 
From what I understand `if the string is alpha it writes it letter by letter`. `If not` - here I get stuck with this `j`. 
Also, why it makes it `0` at the end of the while loop? 
Is there a way to somehow see what the code does line by line?

Comment: Please configure your editor to not show whitespace characters or line numbers, and copy the code over again.

Comment: The code assumes set of letters (`'a'` to `'z'`) is contiguous.   It will not work as described for character sets in which the letters are not contiguous.

Comment: @StoryTeller I've proposed an edit, it just needs to be accepted.

Comment: @muXXmit2X - Kudos. Though I hope the OP will learn their lesson and not rely on good Samaritan to clean up after them.

Comment: *"Is there a way to somehow see what the code does line by line?"* - Yes, it's called a debugger. Useful little programs those are.

Comment: Regarding the comment by @Peter about the character range, please read about [`islower`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/islower) which check if a character is a lower-case letter regardless of character set used. Your `ft_count` function will still be problematic though, but nothing an array and some pointer arithmetic can't solve.

Comment: So, uh, `ft_is_alpha()` is a non-portable version of the standard function `isalpha()`, with inverted logic in the return value (0 means "yes", 1 means "no"). I would suggest not continuing with this code, I wouldn't want whoever wrote it to teach me much.

Comment: By the way, the logic of your `ft_is_alpha` function is reversed from its name. It returns true if the character is *not* an alphabet character. Either rename to e.g. `ft_is_no_alpha` or reverse the logic everywhere it's used.

Comment: Function `ft_print` is using `j` to control the loop of how many are printed, but it is poor style. Instead of initialising `j` at the point of definition and again *after* the loop, it would be more clear to set `j = 0;` at the point of use. That loop also inefficiently calls `ft_count` in each iteration, even better would be to set `j` to this value at the start of the loop, and count `j` downwards.

Comment: `ft_is_alpha(x)` is closer to being a non-portable form of `!islower(x)`, than to a call if `isalpha()`, since it only tests - in a non-portable manner - for lower case letters.

Comment: Thank you for pointing the editing mistakes. It's the first time I am posting and i actually thought that those helped readability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for misunderstanding the code is that the function `ft_is_alpha`

```
int ft_is_alpha(char c)
{
  if ((c >= 'a') && (c <= 'z'))
    return (0);
  else
    return (1);

}
```

is defined logically incorrectly. (More precisely the reason for misunderstanding is badly written code.:) ) The function should return `1` in case when a character is in the range `['a', 'z']` and `0` otherwise.

For example

```
int ft_is_alpha(char c)
{
    return c >= 'a' && c <= 'z';
}
```

And after changing the function `ft_print` appropriately

```
void ft_print( char **argv )
{
    int i = 0;

    while ( argv[1][i] )
    {
        write( 1, &argv[1][i], 1 );

        if ( ft_is_alpha( argv[1][i] ) )
        {
            int n = ft_count( argv[1][i] );
            for ( int j = 0; j < n; j++ )
            {
                write(1, &argv[1][i], 1);
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

the program will be more readable and clear.

Thus when a next character `argv[1][i]` is in the range `['a', 'z']` it is additionally outputted `argv[1][i] - 'a'` times.

Answer (score 1):

The letters are multiplied by the inner `while` loop:

```
  while (j <= ft_count(argv[1][i]))
  {
    write(1, &argv[1][i], 1);
    j++;
  }
```

`ft_count()` returns the letter's alphabetical index. Since the loop increments `j` each time, it will repeat as many times as that index.

This also answers your second question about why it assigns `j = 0;` after the loop. This is so that the next time will start at `0` again. If it didn't do that, the next letter would only be repeated by the difference between its index and the previous letter.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the line by line explanation below.

```
while (argv[1][i])                       // While loop
{
  if (ft_is_alpha(argv[1][i]))          // Checks if the character is not in the range of aplhabets
                                        // Note - that the logic in this function is inverted as mentioned by others.
  {     
    write(1, &argv[1][i], 1);           // If not within 'a' to 'z' it will directly print the character.
  }
  else
  {
    while (j <= ft_count(argv[1][i]))   // This function returns the difference between the character and 'a'
                                        // e.g. for 'c' it will return 3    
    {
      write(1, &argv[1][i], 1);         // In the loop, this will write as the character as many times as j.
                                        // e.g. if the character is 'c' it will write ccc
                                        // if 'f' it will write ffffff
      j++;               
    }
    j = 0;
  }
  i++;
}
```